# order array by key

Tags: php

can someone help me please? I would like to order this multi dimensional array items[]
by the key 'rel'

```
print_r ($items) will output:



 Array(

 [36] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [name] => mp4
        [total_items] => 58
        [rel] => 5.3015
    )

[61] => Array
    (
        [id] => 61
        [name] => mp3
        [total_items] => 61
        [rel] => 21.7269
    )

[63] => Array
    (
        [id] => 63
        [name] => avi
        [total_items] => 43
        [rel] => 2.254
    )
 )
```

and I need to be: first [61] sencond [36] and then [63]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```
function array_sort(&$array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

So you would use it like this:

```
array_sort($items, 'rel');
```

Comment: This should be added to php's standard library considering how often people ask for it here.

Comment: @PMV they ask, because they do not read documentation ;) There is a function that allows you to do that without the need for so much code. Using [closures](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) it is even more simple.

Comment: @Tadek, you can only use anon functions in newer versions of php

Comment: @Neal But you can use `usort()` since PHP4, and PHP5.3 is quite old now (was released in the first half of 2009) - come on, it sure is not something "new"

Comment: @Neal Correction: in this case it is about `uasort()` function.

Comment: You have to write additional code for uasort() and many people aren't comfortable with callbacks.

Comment: thank you very much to all you guys! I think like PMV on considering to include to php functions library!

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that and it is called [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

See the first and second example from the documentation of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and adapt it, maybe like that:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['rel'] == $b['rel']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['rel'] < $b['rel']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($your_array, "cmp");
```

Did it help?

**EDIT:**

Also, if you have PHP version higher than 5.3, you can use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
uasort($your_array, function($a, $b){
    if ($a['rel'] == $b['rel']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['rel'] < $b['rel']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

**EDIT2:**

I have made a mistake: `usort()` is used for sorting without maintaining key association (see [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)), the `uasort()` function is what you need. I have corrected examples above.

Comment: this is a multidimensional array. How does `$a['rel']` exist?

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are just elements of the array that is sorted. And because these elements are arrays themselves, they also have keys (unless they are empty) - in this example each element of the array has `rel` key. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
$rel = array();
foreach ( $items as $key => $value )
{
    $rel[$key] = $value['rel'];
}
array_multisort($rel, SORT_ASC, $items);
```

Comment: That basically just sorts the individual arrays, no?

Comment: No: "array_multisort() can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions." Reference: http://us.php.net/array_multisort

Answer (score 0):

Try `usort()`, write your own little callback comparison function.

http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php